# How to add an additional hyperlink to Javascript tabify link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using some JavaScript to create a retained hover over effect and to use tabs.

Here is an example of what I am doing here - http://jsfiddle.net/kU9NY/

What I would like to do is add a link to each of these tabs. Basically the user gets a preview of the page in the tab and then by clicking on one of the tabs it will take them to the full page.

I am not sure if this can be done as the links are already taken up by the tabs.

e.g.

```
<a href="#Booking">BOOKINGS</a>
```

Can I add an additional linksome how or is there some JavaScript wizardry I can implement?

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an onclick event on the anchor tag and use window.location to redirect

```
<a href="#Booking" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">BOOKINGS</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanking you Michael Sanchez

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kU9NY/14/

However, there might be an even easier way if you have an easier time setting the url other places, this is just a suggestion to get your brain going :)

```
of course you'd have to do one without the remove() in your onload
```

You could also set the link text in an data-linktext attribute and make that interchangable as well.

The same code with a wrapping function: http://jsfiddle.net/kU9NY/16/